# input a value then use that value as input

Tags: c++

I am trying to get an input and then use the input value for another `cin` value. These codes cannot be compiled (expected), just to illustrate my idea:

```
class StaffLogin : public ShareData {
private:
    string ID;
    void authorized()
    {
        struct staffs
        {
            string username;
            string password;
        };
        staffs id700014089, id700014090;
        id700014089.username="Robin";
        id700014089.password="c++ is fun";
        cin>>ID;
        cout<<"Username: ";
        cin>>"ID".username;
        cout<<"Password: ";
        cin>>"ID".password;
    }
};
```

For example, I want to get an ID from user, so `cin>>ID` . Then use the value in another input (`cin>>"the ID from previous cin".username`) so that I can easily create a new id, username and password for a new user. Please tell me if there is a method to do it?

EDIT: OK I found a simpler solution just by using 

`map<string,string> stafflist;
map<string,string>::iterator it;`
Without any struct. Just comment in case some of you need more details. ;)

Comment: Why would you want to name your variable from an user input? That's impossible in C++ btw - variable names are compile only and the input comes during runtime

Comment: You should create a struct for doing something like this because you cannot rename a variable in C++ .

Comment: You cannot use the value of a variable as the name of a variable. Once your program is compiled, variable names are meaningless.

Comment: I guess you want a `std::map<unsigned long, staffs>` which will allow you to store `staffs` objects associated to an ID key.

Comment: I want to verify the id first like I enter 700014089. It prompt for the username with existing id with "cin>>700014089.username" Then if "700014089.username" matches "700014089.Robin", the user is authorized (same way as passwords as well)

Comment: I guess you are familiar with Javascript or other dynamic languages which enable such functionality. However, while in Javascript you can think about objects as pool of properties and their values, in C variables are only memory locations. See @Jonathan Wakely's answer about std::map to know how to use keys and values in C.

Answer (score 3):

C++ is not a dynamic language, so to create objects dynamically with names supplied from user input you need to use some kind of key-value container that let's you associate arbitrary names with objects. The standard solutions in C++ are `std::map<Key, Value>` or `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>`.

Assuming that staff IDs are always numbers you could do it like this:

```
struct staffs
{
  string username;
  string password;
};
using StaffDirectory = std::map<unsigned long, staffs>;

StaffDirectory staff_directory;

// ...

unsigned long id;
if (std::cin >> id)  // read the ID
{
  // check the ID
  if (!validateStaffID(id))
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid staff ID: " + to_string(id));
  staffs s;
  if (std::cin >> s.username >> s.password) // read username and password
  {
    // add the object to the map, using `id` as the key
    staff_directory[id] = s;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. :3 I am glad that I joined stackoverflow. You guys are so passionate in helping people until I don't have time to reply every answers and comments. THANK YOU EVERYONE I LOVE YOU ALL!

Comment: Oh no "avoid comments like thanks". Hey sir what should I type in 'StaffDirectory'? The correct format can sir show me? Sorry again for noob questions.

Comment: I don't understand what "what should I type in 'StaffDirectory'?" means. You don't type anything into it. It's a container for your other objects. I suggest you get a good book on C++ and read it, it will explain how to use containers and other data structures.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is not quite possible. However, you can do this:

```
struct staffs {
    string ID;
    string username;
    string password;
};
staffs s;
cin>>s.ID;
cout<<"Username: ";
cin>>s.username;
cout<<"Password: ";
cin>>s.password;
```

Or depending on what you want to do with this data you could also use a `std::map<string,staffs>` to have an explicit mapping between the ID (first template parameters) and the users data (stored in staffs).

EDIT: before reading your comments, it wasnt really clear to me what you want to do. In the meantime Jonathan Wakely already gave an more detailed example of using a map.

Comment: Thank you for replying! But the project will have a lot of staffs and I will need to get the correct "cin" for every different staffs. Like when "s2" try to login it will need "cin>>s2.username" and next time "s3" try to log in it will need "cin>>s2.username". Can anyone show me how to use std::map<string,staffs>? I am really a newbie and don't know much about complicated codes. T.T

Comment: Oh sir I am just to slow to type comments, sorry! By the way I really appreciate your passionate and helps you offered. :3 Never expected much help from online communities. But stackoverflow gave me hope!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Staff
{
    string username;
    string password;
};
int main()
{
    map<string, Staff> _map;

    while (true)
    {
        string id;
        Staff staff;
        cout << "Enter id: ";
        cin >> id;

        bool idExists = true; //assume id exists
        if (idExists)
        {

            cout << id << ": username: ";
            cin >> staff.username;
            cout << id << ": password: ";
            cin >> staff.password;

            _map.insert(_map.begin(), pair<string, Staff>(id, staff));
        }

        int choice;
        cout << "\nAdd? {1 or 0}: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        if (choice != 1)
            break;
    }

    for (auto it = _map.begin(); it != _map.end(); it++)
        cout << "\n Id: " << it->first << ": Username :" << it->second.username << " , Password: " << it->second.password << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it because `ID` is not a structer object. If you want to use structer variables, firstly, you must to create struct object.

**Example:**

```
staffs st;  // **create staffs structer object**
cin>>st.ID;
cout<<"Username: ";
cin>>st.username;
cout<<"Password: ";
cin>>st.password;
```

Comment: Sir Khamill I think you misunderstood my purpose. I want the 'st' in "st.username" to be inputed by user instead of a constant value to give the 'cin>>(user value).username' flexibility. I do not understand how to use the map<key,value>  method, so bro please help me.

Comment: if you want to use  map, you can use this:
** ` _map.insert(_map.begin(), pair<string, Staff>(ID, st));`**

Comment: Sir Khamill, but I am not trying to add values into my map. I just want to do this "staff_directory[id] = s"so that I can do "cin>>s.username", but compiler come out errors once I type this line although the map name, and struct objects are correct already. Or adding values can help in my situation? Please give me more details, I'd really appreciate them.